# how can i pass perl variable in sql file in perl script

Tags: sql, perl

here i have 3 variable in perl and i m passing those variable in one db.sql file in sql query line then executing that db.sql file in same perl file but it's not fetching those variable.

```perl
$patch_name="CS2.001_PROD_TEST_37987_spyy";
$svn_url="$/S/B";
$ftp_loc="/Releases/pkumar";
open(SQL, "$sqlfile") or die("Can't open file $sqlFile for reading");
while ($sqlStatement = <SQL>) 
{
   $sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlStatement) or die qq("Can't prepare $sqlStatement");

   $sth->execute() or die ("Can't execute $sqlStatement");
}
close SQL;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

following is the db.sql file query

```
insert into branch_build_info(patch_name,branch_name,ftp_path)
values('$patch_name','$svn_url','$ftp_loc/$patch_name.tar.gz');
```

pls help me how can i pass the variable so that i can run more the one insert query at a time.

Comment: What error messages or other info about what goes wrong do you have? Note that you are using two different variables in `$sqlfile` and `$sqlFile`, and `"$/S/B"` contains the dollar sign meta character, which will be expanded to `$/`, which is the input record separator.

Comment: You can't prepare the statement `'insert into branch_build_info(patch_name,branch_name,ftp_path)'` which is what you're *trying* to do by going one line at a time--given that your `db.sql` file is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can influence the sql-file, you could use placeholders

```
insert into ... values(?, ?, ?);
```

and then supply the parameters at execution:

```
my $ftp_path = "$ftp_loc/$patch_name.tar.gz";
$sth->execute( $patch_name, $svn_url, $ftp_path) or die ...
```

That way you would only need to prepare the statement once and can execute it as often as you want. But I'm not sure, where that sql-file comes from. It would be helpful, if you could clarify the complete workflow.

Answer (score 0):

there's a few problems there - looks like you need to read in all of the SQL file to make the query, but you're just reading it a line at a time and trying to run each line as a separate query. The `<SQL>` just takes the next line from the file.

Assuming there is just one query in the file, something like the following may help:

```
open( my $SQL_FH, '<', $sqlfile)
   or die "Can't open file '$sqlFile' for reading: $!"; 

my @sql_statement = <$SQL_FH>;

close $SQL_FH;   

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( join(' ',@sql_statement) )
   or die "Can't prepare @sql_statement: $!";

$sth->execute();
```

However, you still need to expand the variables in your SQL file. If you can't replace them with placeholders as already suggested, then you'll need to either `eval` the file or parse it in some way...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [String::Interpolate](http://search.cpan.org/~nobull/String-Interpolate-0.3/lib/String/Interpolate.pm) module to interpolate a string that's already been generated, like the string you're pulling out of a file:

```
while ($sqlStatement = <SQL>) 
{
   my $interpolated = new String::Interpolate { patch_name => \$patch_name, svn_url => \$svn_url, ftp_loc => \$ftp_loc };
   $interpolated->($sqlStatement);

   $sth = $dbh->prepare($interpolated) or die qq("Can't prepare $interpolated");

   $sth->execute() or die ("Can't execute $interpolated");
}
```

Alternately, you could manually perform replacements on the string to be interpolated:

```
while ($sqlStatement = <SQL>) 
{
   $sqlStatement =~ s/\$patch_name/$patch_name/g;
   $sqlStatement =~ s/\$svn_url/$svn_url/g;
   $sqlStatement =~ s/\$ftp_loc/$ftp_loc/g;

   $sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlStatement) or die qq("Can't prepare $sqlStatement");

   $sth->execute() or die ("Can't execute $sqlStatement");
}
```